# When to know System.in ending

Tags: java

According to the teacher our code reads from System.in, and that the program ends when we reach the end of the standard input file.
how do I know that I have reach the end?

As requested here is my best translation.--

- ORIGINAl:"O sistema deverá ler comandos da entrada padrão
  (System.in), processando-os um a um e enviando os resultados para a
  saída padrão (System.out). A terminação ocorrerá quando for atingido
  o fim de ficheiro na entrada padrão."
- TRANSLATED:"The system should    read commands from the standard
  input (System.in), processing them    one by one and sending the
  results to the standard output    (System.out). The ending should
  occur when the end of the file in the    standard input is reach"

What I have so far.

```
public static void readInput()
    {
        java.util.Scanner in;
        String tmp = "";
        try {
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                tmp = in.next().toUpperCase();
                commandAnalyzer(tmp, in);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf(e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to my world of being a student. And the teacher is like deal with it.

Comment: Why not post your actual assignment text?

Comment: I can if you want but its in Portuguese

Comment: Consider translating it as best you can to English.

Comment: depends on the kind of stream it point to

Comment: I asked my colleagues and they say that in linux everything is a file. Well im on windows so I guess my teacher is on linux.

Comment: @JoaoSilva use google translator and translate it into english. Unless we understand what the actual problem how can we help

Comment: @javaBeginner Already done

Comment: @javaBeginner he already has translated

Comment: @JoaoSilva Just now saw the translated one

Answer (score 3):

`System.in` references an input stream. This input stream can be any source of input. It could be a file or it could be another programs output or just input from arguments passed in by the user.

If you are expecting the input to be file you may want use a reader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8")); 
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Scanner` class, then, you know the end of input when `scannerObject.hasNext()` returns `false`.

Comment: Thats what Im doing but the code never ends it just waits for another command

Comment: press CTRL+D or CTRL+Z to end the input and send EOF

Comment: @JoaoSilva in your code,it will never stop because you have not put any condion.while(in.hasNext()) is always true so the code never ends.You can use System.exit(0) to end the program

Comment: why should it end by itself? System.in has not sent an EOF token for the scanner to stop.

Comment: @javaBeginner why is it.hasNext() always true im doing the in.next() it should sonner or latter have no more text to process?

Comment: Im not saying that the code i posted should end, I'm saying thats the objective of the assignment.

Comment: @JoaoSilva that's not the way it works. `System.in` waits and waits for more input until an EOF is sent to the program. And it is even ready to wait forever until you don't send it an EOF.

Comment: That's the point @JoaoSilva, `until the end of file in the standard input is reached`<- And the only way to send END OF FILE in command prompt is to use CTRL+D(or CTRL+Z, forgot which one)

Comment: Ok so System.in is waiting forever and I have no means to know when there is no longer text in there?

Comment: You have only one way to know when there's no longer text in the System.in and that's by sending an EOF signal(using CTRL+D or CTRL+Z)

Comment: @JoaoSilva how many inputs you want from System.in,based on that you can use a count.If count exceeds then call system.exit?Please tell me your exact requirement

Comment: @javaBeginner Its not a certain number of imputs its any number the user wants it to be